# How do I check if update for my Windows Phone App is available?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, app-update

How do i make my app itself whenever there is a new version on the store? I have researched enough but nothing seem to have worked for me.. Help required! Thank you

Comment: Make it read something from the internet.. It's like your app reads a text from internet and store it. then check it again and match the stored data.. If stored data doesn't match the newly read data, it means there's an update.

Comment: I tried doing that but it could not make it happen for some reason. It will be very helpful if you could just elaborate or provide me with some code

Answer (score 1):

I use this https://github.com/igorkulman/Kulman.WP8/blob/master/Kulman.WP8/Services/WindowsPhoneInformationService.cs, works for Windows Phone 8 and 8.1 Silverlight apps.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8.1 automatically updates apps, so this shouldn't be necessary any more for the general case.

If your app has a server component that requires the client be in sync then you can send the client version to the server to catch the case where users haven't yet upgraded.